# Unable to connect to any Wifi in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wifi-hardware-switch

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I've tried connecting to the AT&T router in my apartment, but I cannot see the symbol. I've tried installing drivers for the WiFi Router from Additional driver but there no drivers in the list.

output of the `lspci` command is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Comment: What WiFi device do you have?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat I have an AT&T Router in my apartment

Comment: Same situation with 16.04 for me.  Solution below still worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the installation USB, insert it and and drill down to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag bcmwl-kernel-source to your desktop. Do the same with pool > main > d > dkms and drag dkms to you desktop. Then install:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: `dpkg: error processing archive dkms*.deb (--install):  
cannot access archive: No such file or directory  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
dkms*.edeb`

Comment: Is it on your desktop? cd ~/Desktop && ls

Comment: I copied the file in the Desktop folder of my Windows OS and not Ubuntu OS. :)

Comment: Please fix it and try again.

Comment: Thanks a ton @chili555 it worked. But, now it's showing some CA certificate error. :(

Comment: Please tell us what it is exactly.

Comment: In case of compile error, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1307744/comments/11

Comment: I can't run dpkg because my ubuntu has no ggc and other dependencies needed for dpkg. :( how can I install the driver without it?

Comment: @LucasAzevedo please ask your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 here it is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130198/fresh-ubuntu-18-04-installation-has-no-dpkg-and-no-internet

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the drivers for your Broadcom chip. To do so, open a terminal.

Run these two commands with a working internet connection (Use Ethernet):

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2/+build/5254885/+files/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb -O driver.deb
sudo dpkg -i driver.deb
```

Reboot and enjoy your WiFi!

---

If you cannot connect to the internet, you can of course [download the file here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2/+build/5254885/+files/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) on Windows, ***save it to a USB stick***, reboot into Ubuntu, mount the USB stick, and double-click on the `.deb` file.

Comment: @Whaaat Thanks a ton!!!!!! I wanna know one last thing, can I download it on Windows and then install on Ubuntu?

Comment: @user2607744 Edited the post.

Comment: @user2607744, If this helped you (solved your problem), please click the check mark. Thanks!!

Comment: @Whaaaat please check this link (http://i.imgur.com/JmbYoEw.png) The issue isn't solved yet!

Comment: @user2607744 Can you run this command in your terminal? `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your/flash/drive/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64`?

Comment: You may actually need to plug in to Ethernet to fix this one. Sorry...

Comment: If you have the install CD or USB you used to install Ubuntu, you can find _dkms_ there. Also here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/dkms Notice there are several dependencies.

Comment: Hey @chili555 I have the USB with Ubuntu, with which I installed the OS, but can show me how should I install the WiFi driver?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same issue.

I'm using Android 4.4.2 and I accessed the Internet via USB Tethering. The option was hidden in my settings so I used the free "USB Tethering Pro" app for the job.