# Compile BCM4352 Wireless Driver

Tags: compiling, broadcom, gcc

I was trying to compile the latests driver v.6.30.223.271-2 published in Broadcom site, reading this post I try to compile the driver following:
`http://askubuntu.com/a/652844`

But I have an error message:

`KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd
`make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:148: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:676: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'BCM4352/Broadcom'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

I try to disable **fstack-protector-strong**

`scripts/config --disable CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG`
but have this message from terminal:

`bash: scripts/config: No such file or directory`

gcc version is 5.4.0 and have kernel 4.4.0-31-generic (Ubuntu 16.04  64 bits)

Essential (12.1ubuntu2) and Linux-headers (4.4.0.31.33) apparently installed OK. Also checked and confirmed driver is 64bits STA file: `https://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11`

I need another package to successful compile this driver?

Comment: Is yours a 32- or 64-bit system? `arch`

Comment: Is 64 bits system.

Comment: I don't understand this from your terminal output: "CONFIG_X86_X32" Are you certain you downloaded the 64-bit version? Also, be certain that headers and build-essential are installed: `sudo dpkg -s build-essential` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-generic` If either is missing, install them and try again.

Comment: Both, essential and headers are installed OK, checked and downloading again but same error, updated some lines.

Comment: Please show me the full path in the terminal where you ran 'make' I just compiled it myself and I see: `chili@T440p:~/Downloads/bcmwl/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271$`

Comment: Extracted the tar file in:   `Downloads/Drivers/Broadcom BCM4352/Broadcom`   and run make in same directory from terminal:    `jabberwocky@jabb-ltp-ubuntu:~/Downloads/Drivers/Broadcom BCM4352/Broadcom$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is a space in the name:

> ~/Downloads/Drivers/Broadcom BCM4352/Broadcom

Linux and, especially 'make' is troubled by spaces. Please rename the file to something like:

> ~/Downloads/Drivers/Broadcom_BCM4352/Broadcom

Then try again:

```
cd ~/Downloads/Drivers/Broadcom_BCM4352/Broadcom
make
sudo make install
```

I assume that you are compiling this driver because you are having trouble with your wireless. I suspect this driver will not solve it. After it is installed and you reboot, please start a new question to tell us the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Your are the man.... yeap now I can compile the .ko driver. I can't find a clue about this "little issue" in web. Thank you very much.

Comment: Work fine, wi-fi connected with new driver. I was compile this driver to check if this will fix my bluetooth errors, already asked here:    `http://askubuntu.com/questions/809318/bluetooth-bcm20702a1-cant-connect-devices`   .  I think was caused by wifi driver, but still have bluetooth issues :(  .