# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi stopped working after 2 years on Dell XPS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, dell, broadcom

I've had a Linux installed on my Dell XPS laptop for 2 years and it has suddenly stopped recognising any Wifi Networks.

In Settings > Networks the options are:

```
Wired
VPN
Network Proxy
```

More Info:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71ffff
```

and

```
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s20u1c4i2  no wireless extensions.

$ grep -R brcm /etc/modprobe.d
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist brcm80211
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist brcmfmac
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist brcmsmac
```

Chilli555 - Thanks! 
Edit 
uname -r
4.15.0-23-generic

David Foeerster- 
dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' linux-* | sed -ne 's/^i //'

Nothing happens

Edit: Elder Geek suggestion:

sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' linux-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //'`? Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590442/how-can-i-install-broadcom-wireless-adapter-bcm4352-802-11ac-pcid-14e443b1-r/590450

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question as requested. Thank you for all your help. Issue still not fixed, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Sometimes WiFi breaks and restarting helps.

Comment: Hi, doesn't make any difference.