# firmware cache?

Tags: drivers

I've noticed something that I can't explain:
I had this line in dmesg

```
bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2009.hcd failed with error -2
```

This file doesn't exist so I've downloaded it and put it in /lib/firmware/brcm .

After, this error disappears from dmesg. 
As bluetooth doesn't work, I removed this .hcd file and I don't understand why this error doesn't reappear now. It's like this firmware is copied somewhere.

I found [https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/firmware/core.html](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/firmware/fw_search_path.html) but fw_path_para parameter seems to be not defined for the broadcom bluetooth module (doesn't appear in btbcm), I can't write in /sys/module/firmware_class/parameters/path (even logged  as root), and I don't understand well the part "Firmware cache" of the link.

Does someone can explain that?

Thanks

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your firmware might be missing or corrupted. I had a similar problem which got fixed once I followed [Yadnesh's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091888/bluetooth-not-finding-any-devices-ubuntu-18-04) answer.

1. Find firmware file `BCM43142A0-04ca-2009.hcd` from [this git repository](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm) and add it to `/lib/firmware/brcm/`.
2. Run the following commands:

   `sudo modprobe -r btusb`

   `sudo modprobe btusb`
3. Reboot your machine.