# Bluetooth keeps searching for devices without finding any on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

I've been trying to fix this Problem fo a while, I have a Lenovo Z50-70 20354

I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091888/bluetooth-not-finding-any-devices-ubuntu-18-04) nothing worked

I don't know what info you need so I'm posting this :

**This is the Output for this Code:**`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; rfkill list all; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

**Output:**

`01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:380b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0621]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:14b2 Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[    0.189021] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.233627] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.683948] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.683963] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.683967] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.683969] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.683972] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.897326] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    3.898326] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    3.914326] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    3.915319] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    3.952416] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.952420] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[    3.971562] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    5.781237] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.781239] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.781243] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.983768] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[    5.984337] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   32.538801] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.538808] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.538812] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11`

And this is the output for this Code`lshw`

the Output is :

```
description: Computer
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smp vsyscall32

 Core  description: Motherboard
   physical id: 0
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 15GiB
 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 2634MHz
      capacity: 3100MHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 0b
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
      resources: irq:0
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 0b
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:47 memory:c3000000-c33fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
    *-multimedia:0
         description: Audio device
         product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 0b
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:50 memory:c3610000-c3613fff
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series USB xHCI HC
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:43 memory:c3600000-c360ffff
    *-communication
         description: Communication controller
         product: 8 Series HECI #0
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
         resources: irq:46 memory:c3618000-c361801f
    *-multimedia:1
         description: Audio device
         product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:49 memory:c3614000-c3617fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: e4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:40 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:c3500000-c35fffff
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: enp1s0
            version: 10
            serial: 68:f7:28:98:df:c3
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
            resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c3504000-c3504fff memory:c3500000-c3503fff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
         version: e4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:41 memory:c3400000-c34fffff
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
            vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlp2s0
            version: 01
            serial: 38:b1:db:d9:4b:4d
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.116 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:19 memory:c3400000-c3407fff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
         version: e4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:42 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:c2000000-c2ffffff ioport:b0000000(size=301989888)
       *-display
            description: 3D controller
            product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            version: a2
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
            resources: irq:48 memory:c2000000-c2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series USB EHCI #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:c361c000-c361c3ff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: 8 Series LPC Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:44 ioport:5088(size=8) ioport:5094(size=4) ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5090(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:c361b000-c361b7ff
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 8 Series SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:c3619000-c36190ff ioport:5040(size=32)
```

is there anything I can do? I tried deleting anything related to Bluetooth and install it again nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution for this problem after a long 5 hours of googling around thanks to ALEXEY BOGDANOV <3**

here is the [link](https://dev-pages.info/ubuntu-bluetooth/) for a specified easy to follow tutorial

but instead of Naming the File `BCM.hcd` I kept the name which is `BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd` because that was the exact file I needed.