# Bluetooth pairing problems Ubuntu 20.04: Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationRejected

Tags: bluetooth, laptop, 20.04, blueman

Installed today Ubuntu 20.04 on my Laptop on a second partition.
Unfortunately my Bluetooth suddenly stopped its service and won't connect to my Mouse and Keyboard.
I tried this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working) and also tried to reinstall blueman.
I tried to connect with the terminal and did these steps:

```
bluetoothctl
default-agent
pairable on
devices
trust CA:49:A5:2B:02:C4
pair CA:49:A5:2B:02:C4
```

I get this Error...
*Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationRejected*

Also if I want to access the Bluetooth Modul via the Bluetooth icon in the right corner next to the wifi icon. I get this error:
*blueman-assistant crashed with blueman.bluez.errors.DBusInProgressError in callback(): Operation already in progress*

I hope you can help me and of course thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saw the same error with my new mouse. The steps mentioned [here](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=60692) solved it for me.

The solution is that within `bluetoothctl`, `disconnect`, `untrust`, and `remove` the device by bluetooth MAC address. Then, ensure your device is in pairing mode, `scan` and `connect` to the device.