# Getting the message "[ 0.283078] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed" when booting ubuntu 20.04 then boots normal

Tags: boot, kernel, bluetooth, 20.04, vim

Before, I had problems installing the a200 intel wifi/bluetooth driver which I didn't manage to install properly (I had downloaded it but couldnt use it -  I didn't get it running).
Then I installed instead blueman, dkms etc and got an internal error message. I de installed all that and the internal error message is also gone, but I still get this message when booting.

In the progress, I also edited via vim that "compress gzip" but that didn't help.

I also had entered `rtbth` in `/etc/modules` over vim but I am not sure whether I did that correctly.

Nonetheless, I de installed blueman, blueman manager and dkms but I am still left with that error message shown above, that had not been there before I started to fix my bluetooth problems.

Maybe you can help? (BTW, kernel is 5.4)

Comment: Undo your previous attempts, and do `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`. Reboot. Report back.

Comment: hey thank you a lot!! the error message is gone now :). only downside is that my bluetooth completely doesnt work anymore, but I will either try that some time again or will just get an usb cable for the speakers i used to connect via bluetooth.

Comment: Did you set `compress gzip` back to default? If not, do so, and redo the update-initramfs command. Also, your edit of /etc/modules with rtbth is probably incorrect, and that's probably why bluetooth doesn't work. What is rtbth? What dkms driver had you tried to install? What bluetooth driver had you tried to install?

Comment: ok i put compress back to default (compress=lz4) and bluetooth is working now again.  I was actually trying this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working                                                                                  
sudo apt install blueman

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms

sudo vim /etc/modules
Comment all and add this line

rtbth
Reboot and open

sudo blueman-manager
If still not work, try this

sudo rmmod btusb
sleep 1
sudo modprobe btusb

Comment: So i actually wanted to install this driver from here (for ax 200) https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html  - when I am in ubuntu under "software & updates" it says that "Intel Corporation:Wi_fi 6 AX200" wasn't working. Thats why I actually started trying to "fix" my bluetooth (and my bt also wasnt working every time I boot, but it appears to be working well now). But ye, I still found it frustrating that that device is apparently not fully working.

Comment: I believe that .ucode file is already included in 20.04. Check your /lib/firmware.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: hey, sorry for my late reply and thank you so far. the error message came back after the Software Updater said there would be an update and there was an error while installing through that Updater I think. Everything else is working and under "Software and Updates" it doesnt say anymore that the intel driver wouldnt be working. so its really only that error message apparently not working. I also tried again: "sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)" but it didnt make the error while booting disappear. I didnt make new changes otherwise. And in lib/firmware is latest driver for wifi chip now.

Comment: Right now, I think it might be a 20.04 bug. Ignore it for now. I'll research it some more.

Comment: hey, sorry I either didnt see it anymore or it was temporily away: it says again that the intel driver isnt working. I had removed the driver that I had moved earlier into lib/firmware as there was a later version showing so I thought that I wouldnt need the old version anymore. I removed it and just later I saw that the driver is shown in "Software and Updates" as not working. So I put it back into lib/firmware but I guess I will just leave everything as it is for now cause bluetooth is working and I think it's really not worth the effort.... But cant say whether it was working or I didnt see

Comment: @heynnema, what Ubuntu 20.04 bug are you referring to? Is it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660

Comment: @ndemarco Yes, that certainly looks like it.

Comment: For those lost souls that got here but are using **CentOS**, I fixed it by removing the **safeboot** option in the **BIOS** and rebooting, I also made sure to disable automatic updates since my machine will run unattended and isolated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the comments...

- set back `compress=lz4` in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
- rebuild your ramdisk with `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`
- `reboot`

**Note**: Use the `sudo update-initramfs -c` example, not `sudo update-initramfs -u` variation.

Comment: Here, `compress=gzip` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` fixed it. Thanks for the lead anyway.

Comment: I have to repeat these steps each time I receive a system update for `initramfs`.

Comment: @rationalbeing Leave it set at lz4 compression. I think the problem/bug has been fixed in recent updates.

Comment: @heynnema The compression has always been lz4, but somehow each time initramfs related update is installed I have to rebuild the ramdisk to get rid of the error.

Comment: Relevant bug report: [Bug #1835660](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660)

Comment: I had to set it to gzip, run `sudo update-initramfs -u`, then change it back to lz4, run `sudo update-initramfs -u` one more time, then reboot. Error now gone.

Comment: I am new to linux. How exactly do you get to the directory  /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf, and once there which editor do you use to change compress to lz4? I am using Kubuntu 20.04.1 on a Dell laptop.
Please provide as much details as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @user25406 In `terminal`, type `grep -i compress /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and if it returns =lz4, then leave it alone. If you have another problem, please start a new question.

Comment: @heynnema, it did return compress=lz4 but I am having the same error described in the post above. Any suggestion is welcome. thanks.

Comment: @user25406 Did you do the `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` command using the -c option? If Ubuntu boots after you see the message, ignore the message, as it's kind of bogus.

Comment: No, I didn't run the command. I was stuck in the first part (check=lz4). Now I can do the 2nd. Can you please confirm if $uname -r means $(my username) -r? Thanks.

Comment: @user25406 No, type the command exactly as I have it.

Comment: Did not resolve the crashing issue. Still happens

Comment: @naisanza Please start a new question for your problem.

Comment: How about `sudo apt install lz4` and create the initramfs new.

Comment: @nobody I don't understand your point. lz4 is already there.

Comment: Was not on my system

Comment: what is the logic behind this "fixing the problem"?

Comment: @ColinD Some users have been setting gzip as the compression method. My answer sets it back to lz4 and rebuilds the ramdisk.

Answer (score 1):

Use `compress=gzip` instead of lz4. That worked for me.
Then follow heynnema `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`.
This should work this time.