# Ubuntu on Mac - booting to terminal

Tags: boot, command-line, 20.04, mac

I just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 on a relatively old iMac (2012). It was working fine until I started getting a "initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed" error when restarting the computer. It seems like I will have to change some things via the terminal, but I can't get to the terminal since the computer won't even boot due to the error.

Does anyone know how to boot to the terminal on an iMac running Ubuntu?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245458/getting-the-message-0-283078-initramfs-unpacking-failed-decoding-failed-wh). You can use the USB/DVD (live version) to make the changes if you want an easy way to get there.

Comment: Thank you, could you clarify a little about the live USB/DVD? Is that how I can get to the terminal?

Comment: The USB/DVD that you used to install Ubuntu in the first place. Use that to get to a GUI, mount your hard drive, and then make the changes to the file indicated, and then reboot to see if the changes worked. I could probably type out a longer answer, if needed. I'm just not 100% certain that that's the solution - but it *usually* is.

Comment: Okay thank you, I feel like that should work. However, while I used the 'option' key to boot up the USB that i used to install Ubuntu in the first place, now the 'option' key is not doing anything. The screen goes right to the aforementioned error. :(

Comment: I tried, option, command s, command r, even holding down the power button for a long time. Is there a boot command key combination that I am not trying?

Comment: It'll be the same way you booted to the device to install it in the first place. I don't use a Mac, but it's usually ESC, F12, or sometimes F2. From there, you select your boot device - such as USB or optical disk. You had to have done it at some point to get it to install. Whatever you did, do that again.