# Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed error communicating to TPM chip

Tags: 20.04

PC: intel NUC10i7FNH
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

When I turn on, this error happens.
After this, PC becomes turned off.

How should I do ??

I want to edit /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf.
But I don't know how open a terminal.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "ima: error communicating to tpm chip" messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178285/how-to-solve-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip-messages-during-boot)

Comment: thanks. "error communicating to TPM chip" is solved. but "Decoding failed" exists.

Comment: When you used the error as a [search term](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask), did you see this: [Getting the message "Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed” when booting...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245458/getting-the-message-0-283078-initramfs-unpacking-failed-decoding-failed-wh)?  Though if it doesn't interfere with your booting, I'd probably just leave it alone.