# Read-only and DISK /dev/sdc and initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive

After I installed ubuntu on my usb hard drive, I am able to boot it. However, it keeps showing

> initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

[Getting the message "[ 0.283078] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed" when booting ubuntu 20.04 then boots normal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245458/getting-the-message-0-283078-initramfs-unpacking-failed-decoding-failed-wh) seems to show a solution to that. Then, I found out I can only read my hard drive.
Executing

> sudo update-initramfs -c

Returns

> update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media

the install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS executable thing on my desktop is also not allowing me to install ubuntu on my usb hard drive(not showing /dev/sdc as an option)

EDITED: I am booting from the usb hard drive.
I followed this guide: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#4-boot-selection-and-partition-scheme I think it may be the reason of the read-only... now that I think about it... I will come back to this after school...

Can it be solved? Or should I just get a SSD?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The guide only lead you to set up your usb or DVD to install the OS to ANOTHER drive. So I have to use another usb drive to make the installation work. Don't rufus the .iso to your DESTINATION drive guys.