# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 20.04 - Lenevo z50-70

Tags: kernel, 20.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers, bluetooth-speaker

There seems to be a problem with the bluetooth driver which does not detect/connect to any surrounding bluetooth devices. I have Windows on another partition and i can access bluetooth on there.
As can be seen in the output logs below - there seems to be problem - : `[13696.202909] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2 [13696.202917] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found` 
I tried few other solutions - [Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working) and also uninstalling, reinstalling, upgrading blueman but had no luck.

It will be very helpful if someone helps me out in resolving this issue. I will be happy to paste more logs if needed :)
 Thanks in Advance.

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
```

```
[   36.756490] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   36.756510] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   36.756512] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   36.756514] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   36.756517] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   37.041919] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   37.042919] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   37.058878] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   37.059844] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   37.154737] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2
[   37.154742] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[   39.167934] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   39.168847] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   51.753777] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   51.753780] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   51.753786] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  255.348972] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  255.348977] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  255.348982] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[13224.979350] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[13224.979909] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[13686.947871] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000b4601f89 failed to resubmit (2)
[13696.184935] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[13696.185909] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[13696.201894] Bluetooth: hci0: VrushankLaptop
[13696.202839] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[13696.202909] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2
[13696.202917] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[13698.222770] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[13698.223733] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[13730.575449] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000004f9ecf8b failed to resubmit (2)
[13769.439697] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[13769.440721] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[13769.456776] Bluetooth: hci0: VrushankLaptop
[13769.457745] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[13769.457795] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2
[13769.457800] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[13771.470002] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[13771.470674] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue.
Pasted this file https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd 
Inside the home folder and inside /lib/firmware/brcm 
After downloading the file from github into ~ (home) folder 
`$ sudo cp ~/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm`