# Bluetooth headphones no longer connect in 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, headphones

I've recently updated to 20.04 from 18.04 (Beaver) and I have been using these headphones called [Dudios Shuttle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X2Y64TP), pretty cheap wireless earbuds.  They worked fine in 18.04, but now they don't connect.  Initially I thought I had a bluetooth problem and did [all of these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working), but I found out the bluetooth actually works, as I was able to connect to my phone.  My phone is still able to connect to my earbuds right now.  What might be the reason 20.04 isn't connecting with them?

Comment: :|  I just did that and it worked.  Totally forgot that wow, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I just posted that comment as an answer, please accept it with the checkmark icon in the answer post to indicate that the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the pairings go 'stale' and introduce pairing problems, especially after upgrades or firmware updates on either end of the connection.

Unpair the device completely and re-pair again from scratch.  That may help reestablish the link.