# Bluetooth not working ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

I'm new ubuntu user.

My bluetooth doesn't work, I have already tried reinstalling and this guides:

[Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working)

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-connect-device.html.en

I have only this internal error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zTEZ.png

```
apostal@apostal-0:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:c341 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH FH 2.4G Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

PLS help=)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working