# Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth File Transfer Too Slow .

Tags: bluetooth

Despite reasonable internet speed (see details below), I have a serious issue with getting acceptable file transfer speed from my Bluetooth connection.
I see mention of [something similar here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1879438). But no suggested solution.
Every file of a few MB takes ~ 5 minutes or more.

Can anyone offer any remedy for this ?

**EDIT**

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)

$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28c1 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0a46:9621 Davicom Semiconductor, Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bc2:5030 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex Upgrade Cable STAE104
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0d8c:0008 C-Media Electronics, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[image: Internet Speed Data]

Comment: Speedtest doesn't measure speed of a BT connection. Using Wi-Fi on 2.4 GHz and BT at the same time is always slow. And I can't see how this is related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 I add this in case someone asked the state of my WiFi connection and if (as some have noticed) my internet speed is affected during Bluetooth file transfer. It's related To Ubuntu as I've had no such issue before installing Ubuntu 20.04. BT on Windows was fast enough.

Comment: What is the wireless device?

Comment: My mobile phone. I did a few changes according to this thread here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working  but the improvement is not great. Having trouble sending files to user account on Ubuntu also. File transfer from PC to phone is fast.

Comment: I mean the wireless device of your laptop. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Bluetooth transfer fine to and from PC to phone now when on admin account - quite fast actually. So only problem now is *receiving* files on my user (non-root) account. This implies that the changes I made (done on admin/root account) may be impeding file receiving at the PC. *Transfer forbidden by target device* is the message on the phone.

Comment: Incoming files now being received finally on user account today. Seems like this Bluetooth driver has a sort of familiarization process before it gets working in earnest. Thanks to all here and elsewhere.