# Problems with headphones since the last update of Pulseaudio

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

Because I had a lot of problems with it, I can't connect devices (headphones) from bluetooth when before the last update I can perfectly connected it.

Since 20.04 I had some problems with Pulseaudio on a lot of laptops. Don't know why's this happening, but that's another topic to talk.

PD: I tried with puvacontrol, alsa force-reload, reinstall pulseaudio and delete the config. None of these did make it works.

Comment: Old pulseaudio configuration files can sometimes conflict with newer versions of pulseaudio after package upgrades. So try rebuilding the configuration in your home directory option #3 in the linked answer above.

Comment: Hi Raffa. Tried with the option #3 moving/deleting the config file. No results. The funny thing is, few days ago theses headphones were working perfectly. I don't understand this.

Comment: What are "some  problems" and "a lot of problems"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I find a solution/the problem. I tried with the steps of the first answer:
[Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working)

It's not necessary install any version of python.
Apparently it was the Bluetooth config. Now my headphones are working.

PS: This happens when you change the user without reboot. If you're connected to your machine with the bluetooth headphones connected, in the second user you can't use the headphones, it doesn't detect them like output devices of sound.