# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, laptop

Please help me with my problem.
Suddenly after some updates via Software updater Bluetooth stop working at my msi ps42 modern 8mo (ps428mo-454xua)
Tried some workarounds from here [Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working)
Still got a problem.
What can I do to solve the problem?

Some outputs here:

systemctl | grep -i blue:

```
  run-snapd-ns-bluez.mnt.mount    loaded active     mounted   /run/snapd/ns/bluez.mnt                                                                               
  snap-bluez-229.mount    active     mounted   Mount unit for bluez, revision 229                                                                    
  snap-bluez-266.mount    active     mounted   Mount unit for bluez, revision 266                                                                    
  bluetooth.service       active     running   Bluetooth service                                                                                     
● snap.bluez.bluez.service  failed     failed    Service for snap application bluez.bluez                                                              
● snap.bluez.obex.service   failed     failed    Service for snap application bluez.obex
```

dmesg | grep -i blue:

no output

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 5008 (rev 01)
```

rfkill list all:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Some update, after cold boot up, Bluetooth is on, I can see it by blueman icon in top bar. When I try to open settings I see some devices for a second than I see message: No Bluetooth found
[screen of Bluetooth settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqgN.png)

I can add some extra info, but don't know what could help

**UPD**
Some new info:
after cold bootup Bluetooth is up.

bluetoothctl:

```
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 08:71:90:94:E5:AC Pairable: yes
```

Than i tried to connect to device:

```
 bluetooth]# connect 00:42:79:AF:89:97
    Attempting to connect to 00:42:79:AF:89:97
    [CHG] Controller 08:71:90:94:E5:AC Class: 0x00000000
    Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
    [CHG] Controller 08:71:90:94:E5:AC Powered: no
    [CHG] Controller 08:71:90:94:E5:AC Discovering: no
```

and Bluetooth no more available

```
[bluetooth]# devices 
No default controller available
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell XPS 15 7590 and Bluetooth failed to start without notice. I uninstalled bluez and installed it again and that fixed the problem for me. I have no idea why.

sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove bluez

sudo apt-get install bluez

It would be nice to know why all this happened.