# How can I get bluetooth working again in 20.04.1 and connect a ps3 controller via usb?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

My bluetooth stopped working in 20.04.1 after running a bunch of commands trying to connect a ps3 controller last night

Here's the list of commands I ran from cat ~/.bash_history:

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
sudo xboxdrv --detach-kernel-driver
cls
clear
sudo lsusb
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa
lsusb
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sixad
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa
sixad
sixad -v
sixad -s

sudo sixpair
gcc -o sixpair sixpair.c -lusb
cd sixaxis/
gcc -o sixpair sixpair.c -lusb
sudo apt install lusb
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev libusb-0.1-4
gcc -o sixpair sixpair.c -lusb
sudo ./sixpair
lsusb
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

Then to try to get my bluetooth working tonight I tried:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sleep 1
sudo modprobe btusb
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install blueman
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
```

I then tried everything suggested by Nam in the first answer here:
[Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working)

Second order of business is this ps3 controller. If I run lsusb shows up as `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 145f:0231 Trust USB Gamepad` 
I tried all those commands above but nothing works. It's a Snakebyte SB00566 ps3 controller from Walmart

Any help appreciated, I mainly just want my bluetooth mouse back, I hate my Spectre's touchpad.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think `systemctl stop sixad` is what finally fixed my bluetooth.