# Bluetooth working in a HP laptop but not detecting any device in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, laptop

Laptop Model: . The bluetooth on my HP 250 G4 Notebook PC is working, but not detecting any device. I tried the following the steps suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working), but it didn't work.

Results of `systemctl | grep -i blue` :

> sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d4-1\x2d4:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device
> loaded active     plugged
> /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
> sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device
> loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0
> bluetooth.service
> loaded active     running   Bluetooth service
> bluetooth.target
> loaded active     active    Bluetooth

Results of `dmesg | grep -i blue` :

```
[   19.734675] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22 
[   19.734721] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized 
[   19.734730] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized 
[   19.734735] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized 
[   19.734745] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized 
[   20.278547] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70 
[   20.279542] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06 
[   20.295596] Bluetooth: hci0: frodo 
[   20.295605] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000 
[   20.426538] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found   
[   20.426550] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd' 
[   20.426556] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-216d.hcd' 
[   22.444638] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout 
[   22.445616] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003 
[   36.457400] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 
[   36.457407] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast 
[   36.457420] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized 
[   38.924867] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout 
[   38.925773] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1001 
[   53.284251] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized 
[   53.284259] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized 
[   53.284267] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Yes, this resolved my issue!! Many thanks @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people that might have the same issue, I found the drivers at https://devid.info/ru/68560, by searching my laptop model and then I followed the instructions of the post that @Pilot6 mentioned in his answer: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)