# Bluetooth does not work since installing Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

After a clean install of Lubuntu 20.04 I am unable to get Bluetooth to work. I have tried repair posted by Nam Nguyen answered May 11 '20 at 2:59 [Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working#1238076). His post relates to Ubuntu, but I am using Lubuntu, so I don't no if that's why it does not work. Using Blueman Bluetooth Manager it starts to search, but stops searching before it finds the device I want to use. I did get it to connect with my phone and transfer a file,but now it is all over the place. Search box and others greyed out, on and off as if timed.
Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Bluetooth now seems to work after repair posted by Nam Nguyen answered May 11 '20 at 2:59 Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working.
I uninstalled Bluedevil as it did not work. Now using Blueman installed as part of fix above.
Bluetooth still seems erratic,receiving OK, but will not send notes and sometimes not sending files, but it seems I will have to live with this.