# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS: Cannot find any bluetooth devices

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I'm trying to pair my speakers to my computer via Bluetooth. The first thing I do is go to "Settings" and then go to "Bluetooth". Once I enable it my screen looks like this:
[image]

I've been waiting several minutes and even though I turned on my cellphone and speakers' Bluetooth, it's still trying to find any devices.

I checked that both my cellphone and speakers' Bluetooth worked by pairing them to each other, and the connection is established correctly.

I tried the first two solutions given in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working) but my computer still does not find any device.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

**EDIT**: When I run `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` I get the following message

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.091436] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.121577] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   21.659435] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   21.659464] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.659469] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.659471] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.659475] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.135025] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   23.136022] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   23.152020] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   23.156016] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   24.346628] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[   24.346632] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[   26.369252] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   26.370086] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   48.580829] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   48.580832] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   48.580837] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  217.789270] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  217.789283] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  217.789293] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 done now.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working and that will tell you how to get the firmware from the winterheart github site

Comment: @Jeremy31 it worked. Thanks!