# How to restore ability to connect to Bluetooth devices

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

My desktop has Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Until an Ubuntu update a couple of days ago, when I went to Settings > Bluetooth, there was a list of paired Bluetooth devices such as headphones. Now, instead of that list, that screen shows a large Bluetooth logo and states, "No Bluetooth found. Choose an adapter to use Bluetooth." (translated by me from the interface language, German, so the official English version of this message might be slightly different)

What do I need to do to reconnect my headphones and stuff?

---

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

---

Here is the output from @PabloBianchi's command:

```
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   entsperrt entsperrt
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Dec 07 16:39:42 name-ComputerName systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Dec 07 16:40:38 name-ComputerName systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lsmod | grep bt; rfkill; systemctl status bluetooth.service; journalctl -p warning | grep bt`

Comment: Have you have to install driver for the WiFi+BT in the past? If so then you probably need to do it again due to a kernel update.

Comment: Thank you, @PabloBianchi! I didn't realize the post could be that long.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't remember having to install that driver, but how would I do it?

Comment: If you don't remember doing it then likely you didn't have to, and still don't. To be sure you can run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and [edit] in that information alongside what was requested before.

Comment: Thanks, @ChanganAuto! The output is now in the question, too.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely not what I was hypothesizing. Intel WiFi has native support. But something is wrong with the BT part. Maybe@PabloBianchi can help with that. It's unfortunately above my pay grade.

Comment: Any ideas from the output of lspci, @PabloBianchi?

Comment: [Did you already try](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267032/349837) to remove and add btusb kernel module, and check syslog? `sudo modprobe -r btusb; sudo modprobe -v btusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`, or restart the service `sudo service bluetooth restart`. BTW, never trust commands from untrusted sources, DYOR.

Comment: Thank you, @PabloBianchi! No, I hadn't tried those. Removing and adding btusb shows up in syslog as "deregistering interface driver btusb" and "registered new interface driver btusb." After that and the commands you suggested, re-running your lsmod command still says Bluetooth is dead, alas.