# Asus Bluetooth dongle worked on Ubuntu 16.04, but is not found on (a fresh install of) Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, bluetooth

So I've bought an Asus Bluetooth 5.0 dongle, which worked nicely without any installation on Ubuntu 16.04.
After a complete wipe of my machine and a reinstall to a fresh/vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 I don't see a bluetooth dongle in the system settings.

`lsusb` identifies the dongle as "Bus 003 Device 022: ID 0b05:190e ASUSTek Computer, Inc.", but the 'Settings' app tells me that there's "No Bluetooth found".

Comment: You didn't provide linux kernel stack details for the two releases; options for 16.04 were 4.4 (GA) or 4.15 (HWE), where on 20.04 it's 5.4 (GA) or 5.13 (HWE at 20.04.4); & I'm ignoring OEM options.  I'd be tempted to try the GA kernel stack of 20.04 if you're not already using it; being closer to the older release (you can easily install & have both stacks co-existing on most machines; unless specific closed-source video graphics drivers are installed).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Honestly, I have no ideas about which kernel stack I've got installed. I downloaded and 'burned' "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64" from ubuntu.com. Since I completely wiped my machine I cannot say what was installed on it on 16.04, `ubuntu-drivers list-oem` returns nothing on the current install.

Comment: Ubuntu frequently updates it's drivers. It could have removed drivers for your specific model of Bluetooth dongle. I don't think Linux really supports Bluetooth 5.0, but you can install drivers to still run 5.0. Follow this guide for help: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-install-unsupported-bluetooth-5-0-dongle-on-linux-4bf34aa99fed

Comment: Please be specific with details; though I see you tried, so thank you!. If by Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS *amd64* you meant the server version, the default kernel stack used in GA. If however you meant the same *specifics* but desktop you'll be using the HWE kernel stack. You can use `uname -r` to see kernel running; it'll be a 5.4 kernel if you're using GA, and 5.13 if you're fully upgraded and using HWE (5.11 was found on installation media of 20.04.3 Desktop, but after upgrades that will change to 5.13).  Do note I'm worrying about the extra *patch* details of the kernel, just the first to numbers

Comment: FYI:  If you used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop or 16.04.1 Desktop media to install your 16.04 system, you were using the GA kernel stack, if you used 16.04.2 Desktop or later media to install your system, you'll have been using HWE kernel stack. Server installs usually default to GA but I can't recall accurately for 16.04.

Comment: The machine is on my desk at work and I shut it down some hours ago for a week of vacation. So any updates on this will have to wait, sorry for this and thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I posted didn't 'survive' a reboot.
I adapted it to the solution given in [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398242/759778), which works fine.

- `wget https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/USB-BT500/20200909_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_KERNEL_5.7_COEX_v0202.zip`
- `unzip 20200909_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_KERNEL_5.7_COEX_v0202.zip`
- `cd 20200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v020220200806_LINUX_BT_DRIVER_RTL8761B_COEX_v0202/usb`
- `sudo make install INTERFACE=usb`
- `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`
- Unplug and reinsert the dongle, voila.