# Ubuntu does not recognize connected USB adapter to computer

Tags: drivers, sound, usb, bluetooth

I own the following equipment:

**Samsung Galaxy Buds Live (wireless headphones)**

**Asus USB-BT500 USB 5.0 (bluetooth adapter)**

The situation is as follows, after buying the headphones I needed a USB adapter for my computer, because I did not have one before. After connecting the adapter to the computer, the Ubuntu system still does not detect any connected device, in the Bluetooth tab is automatically disabled after enabling this option, it still does not detect the device and displays an error, about no adapter.
I thought it might be the adapter's fault, and tried it on a Windows computer that also didn't have a Bluettoth adapter before - everything worked as expected there.

So my question is, what could be the reason that the adapter is not detected?

Comment: The device may be simply not supported by Linux. Before you bought the adapter, did you do any research whether it is supported by Linux or not?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392568/asus-usb-bt500-not-recognized-after-update

Comment: If the manufacturer does not provide any linux drivers or spec for its hardware it might not be usable in a linux environment. raj is correct: Check if the hardware is supported by linux before buying it.