# Can not use Bluetooth. Bluetooth turned Off on settings - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I bought a Bluetooth dongle and everything seems to work fine. But some time later it stopped working for no apparent reason.

In more detail, when I try to go to the Bluetooth Settings, or it says it's in airplane mode and I try to turn it on, I'm stuck with info that is shown on the image.

[image: Bluetooth Settings]

I tried to follow [this guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-bluetooth-connectivity-issues-in-ubuntu), but it kept not working.

Comment: Hello. BTW that first link adds nothing to the question you have already said that.

Comment: @David yh I thought someone might not know what I was talking about. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I have fixed it! https://askubuntu.com/a/1238076/1578800 Update for Bluetooth v5 sectiom