# Bluetooth not finding any device.20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

**Hello**

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and my bluetooth works but doesnt find any device and also not visible to any other device. I have installed blueman.Yeah and please, please don't give me link to other questions on this site because they don't work.(I have disabled the bluetooth device from Windows) and checked rf kill list and also enabled bluetooth from bios.

Output of command :- `service bluetooth status`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-01-21 11:18:56 IST; 2h 39min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 5147 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4514)
     Memory: 2.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─5147 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 21 11:18:56 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Jan 21 11:18:56 Piyush-X55C systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 21 11:18:56 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Starting SDP server
Jan 21 11:18:56 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
Jan 21 11:19:00 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 21 11:19:00 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jan 21 13:48:16 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 21 13:48:16 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jan 21 13:48:17 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.155 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 21 13:48:17 Piyush-X55C bluetoothd[5147]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.155 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

Output of `sudo btmgmt info`:-

```
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
    addr A4:17:31:1D:65:54 version 4 manufacturer 91 class 0x000000
    supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr debug-keys 
    current settings: powered bondable ssp br/edr 
    name Piyush-X55C
    short name
```

Output of :- sudo btmgmt find
`Unable to start discovery. status 0x0c (Not Supported)`

When I tried to start discovery by using command :- `bluetoothctl`
the output is :-

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
Failed to set discoverable on: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply
[bluetooth]#
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of: (1) `sudo btmgmt info` and (2) `sudo btmgmt find`? The first command will list information about the BlueTooth device, and the second will scan for discoverable devices nearby.

Comment: Yes Done @Matigo

Comment: This should work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1215336/1013762