# Bluetooth can connect to paired devices but can't identify new devices

Tags: bluetooth

I have `Ubuntu 22.03.3 LTS` and it can connect to already paired devices but it can't locate new devices to pair with (they just don't show up in the devices list). I tried some of the recommendations in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091888/bluetooth-not-finding-any-devices-ubuntu-18-04), but none of them worked.

I tried command `sudo dmesg | grep -i 'blue'`, and I got this output:

```
[    2.225006] usb 3-1.1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    3.507608] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.507635] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.507637] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.507642] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.507645] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.507651] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.665583] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 19 build 0847
[    3.667583] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: product 05ac:821a
[    3.669593] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    3.686589] Bluetooth: hci0: HuLuVicaMacUbuntu
[    6.253099] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.253102] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.253107] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.260951] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   58.907660] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   58.907670] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   58.907680] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  175.881573] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 402 failed: -22
```

It seems to me that it is reporting some error, but I haven't found anything related to it online.

I'll appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

I found that it can't locate devices that where paired once and removed, but it can locate devices that have never been paired before.