# Fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation has no dpkg and no internet

Tags: drivers, apt, 18.04, package-management, dpkg

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it has no wifi driver installed. I know the driver is inside the bootable usb I've used to install it but my system doesn't have all dpkg's dependencies installed.

It asks me for `dkms`, `linux-libc-dev` and `libc6-dev`. How can I install these packages without using internet?

OR

Is there an alternative to install wifi driver without dpkg nor internet?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The wifi issue might be drivers...but might not. Consider confirming that an easier solution is not right under your nose before going down the harrowing road you are asking about.

Comment: I'm quite sure it is the driver, as I've seen multiple people with the same problem. The difference is that they had dpkg installed and solved the driver problem with it.

Comment: If you have the original install DVD, USB or even the SD card, you can use this method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069550/unable-to-use-wifi-card-16-04-macos-dual-boot/1069949#1069949

Comment: @chili555 Thanks. I'll try this soon and let you know the outcome.

Comment: can you plug your computer into the network with ethernet? then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` you could try to get the packages via a repo, and cart them over with a usb stick, but that could be a pain if there are many missing packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069550/unable-to-use-wifi-card-16-04-macos-dual-boot/1069949#1069949) proposed by chili555 worked perfectly. I don't know why the installation doesn't do this automatically but at least we have chili to the rescue!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it’s working as expected.